# How can I add interactive slider add-ons on Blend4Web?

Tags: blend4web

I have created a 3D blender human character, with body proportional slider add-ons. However I need to import this onto the web, where I can adjust the sliders (chest, arms).

I've tried Blend4Web and following various tutorials but with no luck.

Any ideas on what I need to build this out?

Comment: What do you mean by proportional slider add-ons? is it shape keys?

Comment: Yes shape keys to change e.g. The size of the stomach, legs